# Is there a way to store either animation data or arbitrary data in a Collada file from SceneKit?

Tags: scenekit

I'm building a tool to convert an old proprietary mesh+animations file format into Collada DAE files, and so I have been using SceneKit to cheat a bit and just build the geometry and run [scene writeToUrl].

I am able to build correct CABasicAnimations for all the model animations, which are basically sets of morph targets (no bone definitions exist in the original file - only mesh morph targets).

Is there a way to include SceneKit-generated CAAnimationGroup or animations in the file export? Relatedly, is there a way to write and read arbitrary information to and from the export? If I can write and read the total animation duration and the FPS rate then I can reproduce the animations on the game engine side.

Answer (score 0):

All animations should be exported automatically. You can verify that they are correctly exported by opening the Collada file as a xml file. If they are not exporte correctly, then it's a good idea to file a bug.

As for arbitrary data you can maybe use tricks such as using node names to store that information.